# Marketing Cloud - Transactional Messaging API sends - status tracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, email-tracking

I've been using the new Transactional Messaging send functionality in Journey Builder in Salesforce Marketing Cloud and it has been acting a bit unreliably. For example today in my tests, I triggered an e-mail three times and only received it twice, even though the API response and message status in `/messaging/v1/email/messages/{messageKey}` was `("eventCategoryType": "TransactionalSendEvents.EmailSent")` for all 3 messages.

Is there any way to check for sure which e-mails trigerred by an API request via `/messaging/v1/email/messages/{messageKey}` were actually sent/opened/etc? I tried looking for them send under the Tracking tab in Email Studio but couldn't find anything.

Comment: GET on `/messaging/v1/email/messages/{messageKey}` is the right call to grab status. [ENS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/ens.htm) is another option but it'll return exact same info albeit in a more scalable way. Bottom line: according to MC, the email was sent. It may have not left MC (unlikely but possible, despite `EmailSent` status) or left MC but didn't arrive (possible) or got classified as spam somewhere (likely)